# Hide curl output

Tags: curl

I'm making a curl request where it displays an html output in the console like this

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/explicit/functions/ajax.php:87) in <b>/home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/explicit/functions/ajax.php</b> on line <b>149</b><br />......
```

etc

I need to hide these outputs when running the CURL requests, tried running the CURL like this

```
curl -s 'http://example.com'
```

But it still displays the output, how can I hide the output?

Thanks

Comment: Append `>/dev/null` at the end. Read more about File Descriptors on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor?highlight=%28FD%29

Answer (score 527, accepted):

From `man curl`

> -s, --silent
>                 Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. **It will still output the data** you ask for,
>   potentially even to the terminal/stdout
>                 **unless you redirect it**.

So if you don't want any output use:

```
curl -s 'http://example.com' > /dev/null
```

Comment: If you want only errors add the -S flag

    curl -s -S 'http://example.com' > /dev/null

Comment: Note that you can't do `curl -o /dev/null`; it will throw a write error.

Comment: But you can do `curl ... 2>/dev/null` to redirect stderr only.

Comment: @KeithTyler `curl https://www.google.com -o /dev/null` succeeds without errors for me. I'm using `curl-7.58.0`.

Comment: that in my opinion means `wget` should be used instead of `curl` for downloading files.

Answer (score 144):

This one looks more elegant to me:

```
curl --silent --output /dev/null http://example.com
```

Also, if you want to see the HTTP code:

```
curl --write-out '%{http_code}' --silent --output /dev/null http://example.com
```

Full documentation is [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: If you still want errors to be shown you can add the `--show-error` parameter too.

Comment: Even using -sS it still display the headers for me :(

Answer (score 2):

One way to hide cURL output in the `bash` shell, is to redirect both stdout and stderr using the operator `&>` to `/dev/null`

```
curl http://example.com &> /dev/null
```